# Move file/class to another project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Is it possible to move a class to another project with the help of Visual Studio or Resharper (with or without a plugin)?

Would make TDD a tad easier.

**Update**

I use Resharper to create the class directly from the test method. The class is added in the same file as the test class. I can then ALT+Enter on the class to move it to a separate file. After that, I manually drag the file to the other project.

But I would like to have a way to move it to another project directly without having to drag it. Something like ALT+ENTER on the non-existent class and choose "Create in Project Y"

Comment: With visual studio you can just add existing item and then manually change the namespace (in the project you want to move to)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Resharper: Right Click (on file in Solution Explorer) -> Refactor -> Move.

---

Full instructions:

1. Put the cursor over your non-existent class in your test method and press ALT-ENTER
2. Choose to create the class in the context menu
3. Press END to move to the class name
4. Press CTRL+SHIFT+R to bring up the Resharper Refactor menu
5. Press key DOWN for "Move to folder" and then press ENTER
6. Press TAB in the new dialog and then ENTER to show the Target tree view (below the combo box)
7. Navigate with the arrow keys
8. Press ENTER when done

Comment: And how do I move the class to a ***different project*** using Move?

Comment: Usually just cut/paste the source file to the other project - then open the file and ALT+Enter the namespace and let ReSharper refactor it into the right place (based on the folder), not sure if there is a better way, but this is only a couple of clicks

Comment: That's how I do it today, but imho it hurts the flow. That's why I'm asking. Would be better if there was a way to create the file in the corresponding namespace but another project.

Comment: @jgauffin: Right Click on file containing the class in your solution explorer, not on the class declaration. You can specify destination from there (given you are moving the file between projects in the same solution)

Comment: I can't find an option for another project there either. But if I'm in the solution explorer I could just drag the file to the correct project/namespace.

Comment: @jgauffin: don't you see a "target folder" option? You can choose a project from there. And  yes, obviously, you can move file manually, you'll have to fix internals and namespaces afterwards tho. While "Move" does all that in a single transaction and notifies you about missing assemblies

Comment: sorry. My mistake. Was looking in the wrong place in the Move dialog. Too bad that it doesn't work with the keyboard :(

Comment: @jgauffin: if by keyboard you mean hot keys - they work, when solution explorer is focused. You probably need to set those hotkeys first, tho

Comment: No, I mean navigate the target treeview using the keyboard.

Answer (score 17):

"Shift + Drag" in VS Solution Explorer allows you to move file(s). You can then use Resharper to fix the namespaces

Comment: Nice, works in Visual Studio with no extra plugins! On a large project it did cause my Visual Studio to hang for a minute or so, with CPU usage at 30%.